# Python: Create XML file for object detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Good morning. I've just started with machine learning. I completely can't find any good source for creating XML classifier for given images from scratch. I do not want to use any libraries.

Let's assume I have dataset of speed cameras (light container on streets). How to process these images for XML file in order to recognize given speed cameras' pictures.

Comment: This is too broad/vague. Please see: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I need just a good source for creating ones

Comment: _I need just a good source for creating ones_ A source? Creating what?